# mysql GTID replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

i try to use GTID and backdump 
mysql -u root -h xx.xxx.xxx.xx -p < 2015-10-30_all_database.sql 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1840 (HY000) at line 24: @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED can only be set when @@GLOBAL.GTID_EXECUTED is empty.

and i check the slave server

show global variables like 'gtid_executed';

```
| Variable_name | Value                                    |
| gtid_executed | 19718ded-7eca-11e5-bece-00163e001216:1-2 |
```

show global variables like 'gtid_purged';

```
| Variable_name | Value |
| gtid_purged   |       |
```

while the master is 
show global variables like 'gtid_executed';

```
| Variable_name | Value |
| gtid_executed |       |
```

show global variables like 'gtid_purged'
    -> ;

```
| Variable_name | Value |
| gtid_purged   |       |
```

i check slave log

```
#151030 16:12:52 server id 2  end_log_pos 219 CRC32 0xf7210a68  GTID    last_committed=0    sequence_number=1
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= '19718ded-7eca-11e5-bece-00163e001216:1'/*!*/;
# at 219
#151030 16:12:52 server id 2  end_log_pos 366 CRC32 0xd6c11bfa  Query   thread_id=2 exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1446192772/*!*/;
SET @@session.pseudo_thread_id=2/*!*/;
SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=1, @@session.sql_auto_is_null=0, @@session.unique_checks=1, @@session.autocommit=1/*!*/;
SET @@session.sql_mode=1436549152/*!*/;
SET @@session.auto_increment_increment=1, @@session.auto_increment_offset=1/*!*/;
/*!\C utf8 *//*!*/;
SET @@session.character_set_client=33,@@session.collation_connection=33,@@session.collation_server=8/*!*/;
SET @@session.lc_time_names=0/*!*/;
SET @@session.collation_database=DEFAULT/*!*/;
CREATE USER 'root'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password'
/*!*/;
# at 366
#151030 16:14:44 server id 2  end_log_pos 431 CRC32 0x0682aa9d  GTID    last_committed=1    sequence_number=2
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= '19718ded-7eca-11e5-bece-00163e001216:2'/*!*/;**
# at 431
#151030 16:14:44 server id 2  end_log_pos 564 CRC32 0x25289918  Query   thread_id=2 exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1446192884/*!*/;
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'root'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
/*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'AUTOMATIC' /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
```

i CREATE USER and grant to master host root,these generated gtid_executed,but the master have not.
how to execute the 2015-10-30_all_database.sql to slave?
and then use GTID to replication.

Answer (score 0):

Enable GTID then execute RESET MASTER on slave before loading the dump file.